# Problem displaying <ul> element inside div

Tags: html, css

I'm creating footer for my website. I encounter problems that seem to be banal, maybe not. Inside the 'footer' element is a list of 'ul', inside them 'li' with links to social media. The Chrome browser does not display these elements, similarly to Opera and Mozilla. Where is the problem? I am running out of ideas.

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
body {
 font-family: 'Lato', 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
 font-size: 0;
}
.navbar {
 font-size: 18px;
 width: 100%;
 position: fixed;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
 border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.main-nav {
 list-style-type: none;
}
.nav-links,
.logo {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
 vertical-align: middle;
}
.main-nav li {
 text-align: center;
 margin: 15px auto;
}
.logo {
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 22px;
 margin-top: 10px;
 margin-left: 20px;
}
.navbar-toggle {
 position: absolute;
 top: 10px;
 right: 20px;
 cursor: pointer;
 color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
 font-size: 24px;
}
.main-nav {
 list-style-type: none;
 display: none;
}
.active {
 display: block;
}
.background-image img {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}
.container {
 display: flex;
 height: 250px;
}
.column-left {
 width: 33.333%;
 background: #f2f2f2;
 border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
}
.column-center {
 width: 33.333%;
 background: #f2f2f2;
 border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
}
.column-right {
 width: 33.333%;
 background: #f2f2f2;
 border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
}
.container .column-left {
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 20px;
 font-size: 20px;
}
h2 {
 font-size: 23px;
 padding: 15px;
}
p {
 font-size: 20px;
 padding: 15px;
}
.container .column-center {
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 20px;
 font-size: 20px;
}
.container .column-right {
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 20px;
 font-size: 20px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
 .navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  height: 70px;
  align-items: center;
 }
 .main-nav {
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 30px;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
 }
 .main-nav li {
  margin: 0;
 }
 .nav-links {
  margin-left: 40px;
 }
 .logo {
  margin-top: 0;
 }
 .navbar-toggle {
  display: none;
 }
 .logo:hover,
 .nav-links:hover {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
 }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 599px) {
 h2.title {
  font-size: 15px;
 }
 p {
  font-size: 13px;
 }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">     
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/8a84b6b9df.js"></script>

    <div>
        <nav class="navbar">
            <span class="navbar-toggle" id="js-navbar-toggle">
                    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
                </span>
            <a href="https://delightcaptures.com" class="logo"><img src="img/developer.png" alt="Sebastian Falba" width="50"></a>
            <ul class="main-nav" id="js-menu">
              <li>
                <a href="#" class="nav-links">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#" class="nav-links">About me</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#" class="nav-links">Projects</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#" class="nav-links">Contact</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
    </div>
<div class="background-image">
  <img src="img/responsive.jpg" alt="web development">
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="column-left"><i class="fas fa-keyboard fa-3x"></i>
    <h2 class="title">Modern design</h2>
    <p class="description">Fantastic Clean Website Designs</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column-center"><i class="far fa-window-maximize fa-3x"></i>
    <h2 class="title">Responsive</h2>
    <p class="description">Make your website mobile-friendly</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column-right"><i class="fas fa-laptop-code fa-3x"></i>
    <h2 class="title">Quality code</h2>
    <p class="description">Coding best practices are a set of my rules</p>
  </div>
</div>
<footer>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="https://twitter.com/sebastian_falba">Footer</a></li>
  </ul>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 2):

You set the `font-size` to `0` so the text has no height.

Since the text has no height, the `<a>` has no height, so the `<li>` has no height, so the `<ul>` has no height, to the `<footer>` has no height, so you can't see it.